# Sort ascendingly but push zero to end in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I've got a Model with a FloatField. Sane data for this field is within the range of ~`20.0`-`100.0` and there are occasions when data is unavailable. For this, the model defaults to `0.0`.

I want to sort ascending but I want the records with no real data (let's just focus on `0.0` for now) to show at the end (as if they actually had a really high value.

So instead of ranking going

```
0.0, 0.0, 20.3, 23.4, 80.0
```

I would like:

```
20.3, 23.4, 80.0, 0.0, 0.0
```

My first idea was to just change the default to something supermassive but I need to be able to do the same in reverse too. That'll just cause a problem in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I can just use list concatenation to do the work for me. I say "my case" because I need every element in the list and there are no further queries.

```
invalid = list(MyModel.objects.filter(val=0.0))
valid = list(MyModel.objects.exclude(val=0.0).order_by('val'))
return invalid + valid
```

It's by no means a perfect solution. I wonder if there's anything cleaner that can be done inside the database.